# GCM onMessage not called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've scoured the internet and couldn't get my GCM server/client working.

I suspect that its a problem on the client side because I get a success response from the server side.

Anyway I'm clipping both client code and server code.

BTW I can register my device ID.

Server side

```
        Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);

        Message message = new Message.Builder()
        .delayWhileIdle(true)
        .addData("AUB",text)
        .build(); 

        Result result = null;
        try {
            result = sender.send(message, deviceID, 5);
            return "sent " + "Message ID:" + result.getMessageId() + message.getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error: " + result.getErrorCodeName();
        }
```

Client Side

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                Constants.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
        String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, Constants.SENDER_ID);
            Log.v(TAG, "Registered");
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
            Log.v(TAG, GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
        }

    }

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    Constants.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            Log.v(TAG, newMessage);
        }
    };
```

GCMIntentService

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Constants.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = "AUB";
        Constants.displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity_.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="PACKAGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true"/>

<permission
        android:name="PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <!-- Permissions for GCM -->
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <!--  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="PACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I've resolved the issue. Apparently our network was blocking the port 5228.

Comment: have you tried adding a `collapse_key` to the message? Have you tried removing the `delay_while_idle` parameter? I'd try both. If you still don't get the message, then it's probably a problem in the client side.

Comment: @Eran thanks for the reply, I've resolved the issue. Our network was blocking the port 5228.